# ngFor limit rows

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an array. i show its items with `*ngFor` in Angular. I need it to be displayed in 2 rows with as much columns as fits. It may display only 6 of them, but it's ok.

```css
.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
  <div class="col item">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Your question isn't clear enough

Comment: I think, your problem will be resolved by using flex box layout. read about flex basis, flex shrink, flex property and wrap. Apply flex layout to container div (that *ngFor used one)

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid I mean, we have for example, 10 items. I need everything in two rows. So in a specific screen size we can fit only 4 of them. So we have [1,2] in one row and [3,4] in other. Or we can fit 6: [123] and [456].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there're two rows and the elements are fixed size, you can get it using position absolute

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
      <div class="item" [ngStyle]="style[i]">{{item}}</div>
    </ng-container>
    </div>
```

The code:

```
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  //if 1 2 3 4 5
  //   6 7 8 9
  style = this.items.map((_, index) => {
    const top = Math.floor((2 * index) / this.items.length);
    const left = index % Math.floor((this.items.length + 1) / 2);
    return {
      top: top ? top * 300 + 'px' : 0,
      left: left ? left * 150 + 'px' : 0
    };
  });

  //if 1 3 5 7 9
  //   2 4 6 8

  style2 = this.items.map((_, index) => {
    const top = index%2;
    const left = Math.floor((index/2));
    return {
      top: top ? top * 300 + 'px' : 0,
      left: left ? left * 150 + 'px' : 0
    };
  });
```

The .css

```
.wrapper{
 position:relative;
}
.item{
  position:absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekazyi)

**Update** if the only we need is a "grid" like

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

We can get it only with css flex (I always recommended this [link about css-flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

```
.wrapper-flex
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:204px;
  width:100%; //<--neccesary to paginate
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper-flex .item{
  position:relative
}
```

See that we need "fix" the height of wrapper and overflow-hidden.

A variable "page" and a variable "page-size" (and a variable "numPages") allow us to "paginate"

I use a template reference variable "wrapper" in a ViewChild, and in ngAfterViewInit subscribe to the event window.resize

```
  page=0;
  pageSize=this.items.length;
  numPages=1
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    fromEvent(window,'resize').pipe(
      startWith(null)
      ).subscribe(_=>{
        const width=this.wrapper.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
        this.pageSize=Math.floor(width/150)*2;
        this.numPages=Math.floor(this.items.length/this.pageSize)
        this.page=0;
      })
    })
  }
```

NOTE: I update the stackblitz adding the changes

Comment: Thank you Eliso for your help. It's my fault that I didn't mention that I need everything to be in two rows without scrolling. For example: the items are 10, and only 6 of them fit. So we have: [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]. I have no idea how can i implement it.

Comment: @MinaS, Inn this case a css-flex can solve the problem, I update the answer and the stackblitz. I hope this help, else throw more data :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS Grid like this:

```
.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}

:host {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

This will put everything in 2 rows dynamically based on screen size. but since `items` have 150px fixed, in small screens it will expand to more rows to display all the content. Try resizing the window and check the result.

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zuvpxg?file=src/app/hello.component.css

Comment: Thank you Nenad. It seems it doesn't put everything in two rows or I'm wrong. It overflows and reaches to 3 or 4 rows. To make it clear, I have to say I need only two rows. I don't know if grid system is a good tool for that.